# Matlab replacing specific values with condition in matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a mistake with matrices. I don't understand why it isn't working. Here is the code:

```
A = zeros(3,3,3);
A(:,:,1) = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
A(:,:,2) = [1 2 3; 1 2 3; 1 2 3];
A(:,:,3) = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9];
```

I want to replace only values that respect a condition in the 2nd dimension only, using this :

```
A(A(:,:,2)==1)=0
```

but it replaces the 1st dimension ! :

```
0     2     3
0     5     6
0     8     9
```

Is there anyone who can explain to me why that does not work, please?

Comment: You should take a look at `A(:,:,2)==1`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Yes, I know but how can I select only the 2nd dimension for replacing values ?

Comment: `A(:,:,2)==1` outputs a 3 by 3 array which is 2 dimensional, but you need 3 dimensional array as `A(cat(3,false(3,3,1),A(:,:,2),false(3,3,1))==1)=0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this line is that your are applying a 2D mask (A(:,:,2)==1) on A, which has 3 dimensions.

Instead, you can use the following approach:

```
temp = A(:,:,2);
temp(temp==1)=0;
A(:,:,2) = temp;
```

Comment: Thank you @drorco. I found another solution on the same time : `temp(:,:,2) = A(:,:,2)==1; A(temp)=0; `

Comment: @KiMaN glad to help. Did you check your other solution? It seem to have the same issue as what you had in your question

Comment: Yes I checked it with the same example and it's worked, not for you ?